# Syntax error on line 226 but line 226 is empty

Tags: apache, dns, webserver

How are you doing? :D
Im configuring my Apache webserver on debian.
After some configurations i wanted to restart apache and executed:
service apache2 reload

Then I got the following error:
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then I ran "systemctl status apache2.service" and got this:

```
root@root:/etc/apache2# systemctl status apache2.service
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
bled)
   Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-03-13 08:
53:44 EDT; 2 days ago
  Process: 7737 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, statu
s=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 227 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 269 (apache2)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─269 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─270 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─271 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Mar 15 17:43:14 root apachectl[7453]: Action 'graceful' failed.
Mar 15 17:43:14 root apachectl[7453]: The Apache error log may have more info
rmation.
Mar 15 17:43:14 root systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exi
ted, code=exited status=1
Mar 15 17:43:14 root systemd[1]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Se
rver.
Mar 15 18:04:39 root systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 15 18:04:39 root apachectl[7737]: apache2: Syntax error on line 226 of /e
tc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabl
ed/www.test.ml.conf: No such file or directory
Mar 15 18:04:39 root apachectl[7737]: Action 'graceful' failed.
Mar 15 18:04:39 root apachectl[7737]: The Apache error log may have more info
rmation.
Mar 15 18:04:39 root systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exi
ted, code=exited status=1
Mar 15 18:04:39 root systemd[1]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I checked out the file "apache2.conf" on line 226 but realised that this line is blank. [Line 226 on cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUQv.png)
Does anyone know what happened here?

I hope this question isnt all to stupid.

Kind regards
anon

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for https://serverfault.com since it pertains to server configuration and not code.

Answer (score 0):

apachectl configtest

could be useful in such cases

Comment: Then I got this:
apache2: Syntax error on line 226 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.test.ml.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

And line 226 does not have anything.

Comment: There you go with your fix. Add the www.test.ml.conf file and make your settings in this file.

Comment: Hi Peter
I have a general question:
Right now I got a webspace by a public provider and I have an IP address.
I want to setup the DNS for my website so that I can reach it by my domain name.
Which files do I have to configure and how?

Comment: this has to be a question for your dns providers support. Depending on hiis setup there are various possible ways from cool interfaces up to ugly console work in zone files including manual edits of serials.

Comment: Either way, the most you'll have to do on *your* machine is add the site name in the configurations for your services. Actually pointing the name at your IP is done at the service hosting your DNS.